# Registering database to ArcGIS for Server gives null error?

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, database

I'm trying to register a database to ArcGIS for Server 10.2.0 from the web server manager using sde file from ArcMap.  The connection works fine in ArcMap.
But when registering I'm only getting a "null" error.

I can register the database with SDE user but not with the user that has schemas with map services.

We are trying to do this after copying the database from production environment to a development environment.  In production everything works well.

Comment: We have created all our SDE connection files in a shared location which allowed us to run a batch process to just loop through the .sde files and register all those with the data store. Have you verified that the SDE connection file location is visible from the ArcGIS Server machine and it has read access?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Please **edit** the question to specify the operating system in use on the ArcGIS Server host, the database involved, the version of the database, the database client libraries installed on the server, and more details about your ability to register with SDE (which you should not *ever* do) but not with the data owner (which you also should not ever do - instead, use a publication user with the absolute minimum permissions).  Note that GIS SE is not intended to replace Esri Tech Support, so you should certainly call them (you should also be installing 10.2.2)